# Can't install the latest version of private npm package with yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I develop private npm package.
I always publish it to registry with `npm publish` command which according to documentation:

> [--tag ] Registers the published package with the given tag, such that `npm install @` will install this version. By default, `npm publish` updates and `npm install` installs the `latest` tag. See `npm-dist-tag` for details about tags.

Always adds tag latest to the package.
I even double checked if it is tru by using 
`npm dist-tag ls` command. but I've got expected answer: `latest: 1.10.1`

Problem is, that when I use this dependency in package.json like:

```
"@prefix/packageName": "latest",
```

And when I use `yarn install`, then it downloads 1.9.0 version instead of the newest one 1.10.1.

What's going on? How to solve it? What can cause it?

Comment: Have you found  a solution for this. apparently behavior is the same for modules that are in gitlab private registries.

Comment: You have to run `yarn upgrade` which will upgrade all modules in your package.json to their latest supported version

Answer (score 1):

By running `yarn update` we can get the latest version of a package. But running update command comes with a risk which is, It updates every other package listed in `package.json`.

To stop updating unwanted packages we can remove `^` prefix in package version to tell yarn that keep this exact version of this package as it is.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@scope/package-name": "^0.1.9", --> with ^ so it'll fetch the latest.
  "axios": "0.20.0"                --> without ^ so it'll not get the latest.
}
```

There may be better solutions than this, This is what i found as a solution so far.

Comment: OP asked about yarn so the response would be to execute `yarn upgrade`, which is the equivalent of `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

The normal behavior of an `npm install` or `yarn install` is not just installed the latest version.

They verify your `node` and `npm` version, also verify if you have a compatibility issue with another library that you may installed before and requires an oldest version.

So, what you need to do, is verify if the `latest` that you expect is supported for your environment and any previous library requiring the oldest version blocking you the upgrade.

Hope this helps you!